# Changing the pie chart to donut chart staying pie

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have the following code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(20, 10), subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
colors = ['#ff9999','#66b3ff','#99ff99','#ffcc99']
#explode = (0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05)

for i, (groupname, subdf) in enumerate(df_mitigation.groupby('account_name')):
    ax = axs[i // 4, i % 4]
    ax.pie(subdf.cnt, colors = colors,labels=subdf.actual_mitigation_action,autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, pctdistance=0.85)
    centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.70,fc='white')
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
    ax.axis('equal')  
    plt.tight_layout()
    ax.set_title(groupname)
```

but i still getting pie as in the screenshot.[image]

Comment: add `wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5)` as an option to `ax.pie`, and remove your code adding a Circle artist.

Comment: working good! how do i explode them? i tried using explode = (0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05) and adding explode = explode to ax.pie but getting error: ValueError: 'explode' must be of length 'x'

Comment: looks like some of your pie charts only have 3 segments to them? so when you pass in 4 values for explode it complains. you need to make sure that for each pie, the length of your `explode` array is the same as the length of `subdf.cnt`. So, inside your loop, try making `explode=[0.05] * len(subdf.cnt)` or something like that

Comment: this helped me.